# Why doesn't Azure show me my design files CSS, HTML, JavaScript

Tags: python, css, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

When I enter the command: 'az webapp up'
My Django/Python site appears but with no design at all.
When I enter the command: 'python manage.py runserver' in the terminal, the app works as usual with the design.
Am I missing a command? Or maybe something in the settings is not correct?

Comment: Did you run `collectstatic`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want to do:

```
mkdir quickstart        
cd quickstart
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/html-docs-hello-world.git

cd html-docs-hello-world

az webapp up --location westeurope --name <app_name> --html
```

[QuickStart HTML webapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-html)

Or maybe even deploy as a [ZIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli)